# Why, when I posted a topic with PAHO mqtt, did return-8 appear?

Tags: mqtt

Consider:

```
MQTTAsync_responseOptions sendOptions = MQTTAsync_responseOptions_initializer;
MQTTAsync_message pubMsg = MQTTAsync_message_initializer;
int rc = 0;
char msgSend[48] = {0};
json_object *pValue = NULL;
json_object *pObjectSerPro = NULL;
int waitCount = 0;

if (pLoopCount == NULL)
{
    printf("(%s) This is an empty data.\n", __FUNCTION__);
    return DEAL_ERROR;
}

while(!ConnectedFlag && ++waitCount < WAIT_COUNT)
    ;

if (waitCount >= WAIT_COUNT)
{
    printf("(%s) Failed to wait for the connection.\n", __FUNCTION__);
    return DEAL_ERROR;
}

/*
{
    "loop1_count": 1,
    "loop2_count": 2
}
*/

pObjectSerPro = json_object_new_object();

pValue = json_object_new_int(1);
json_object_object_add(pObjectSerPro, LOOP1_COUNT, pValue);
pValue = json_object_new_int(2);
json_object_object_add(pObjectSerPro, LOOP2_COUNT, pValue);


memset(msgSend, 0, 48);
sprintf(msgSend, "%s", json_object_to_json_string(pObjectSerPro));

json_object_put(pObjectSerPro);

sendOptions.onSuccess = onSend;
sendOptions.context = GlobalClient;
pubMsg.payload = msgSend;
pubMsg.payloadlen = strlen(pubMsg.payload);
pubMsg.qos = 1;
pubMsg.retained = 1;

if ((rc = MQTTAsync_sendMessage(GlobalClient, ORENA_SMARTFIRE_EC_RESPONSE_LOOP_REGISTER, &pubMsg,
                                &sendOptions)) != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("(%s) Failed to start sendMessage, return code %d\n", __FUNCTION__, rc);
    return DEAL_ERROR;
}
return DEAL_OK;
```

I intend to encapsulate a JSON message (**{"loop1_count": 1,"loop2_count": 2}**) for publication.

When I changed this code from CHAR msgSend[48] = {0}; to CHAR msgSend[40] = {0};，I encountered a return error code -8, but I looked at the data and said that the problem of returning -8 was due to the version problem. Why?

> (#define MQTTASYNC_BAD_STRUCTURE   -8 
> --Return code: A structure parameter does not have the correct eyecatcher and version number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guess is that the string length exceeds the array size, memory coverage occurs, and the header of the data to be sent is changed.

The answer comes from the author of PAHO: *[return error code -8 #902](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c/issues/902)* (GitHub).

Comment: Please ask the website manager, I deleted the unclear questions, and there are still three questions left. I don't know which of these three problems still has problems. Can you give me a hint and help, otherwise I can't ask questions now.